# Как в wpf изменить календарь в DatePicker?

Tags: c#, wpf

Необходимо изменить всплывающий календарь DatePicker'а, добавив туда две кнопки, чтобы получилось что-то типа этого: 
[image: custom calendar in DataPicker]

Comment: Судя по всему, вам нужно вот это: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126762/A-couple-of-tricks-when-using-the-standard-WPF-NET

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: @VladD Да! То, что нужно, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я попробовал немного улучшить код из статьи [*A couple of tricks when using the standard WPF .NET 4.0 DatePicker control*](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126762/A-couple-of-tricks-when-using-the-standard-WPF-NET). Дополнительный контент задаётся непосредственно в контроле. Это по идее лучше, чем жёстко кодировать список добавленных контролов. Также, расположение можно подправить стилем.

Итак, что нам для этого нужно? `DatePicker` открывает `Popup`, к которому нет простого доступа. Переопределение стиля внутри `DatePicker`'а тоже не сработает, потому что `Popup` находится в другом логическом дереве! А переопределять стиль глобально не комильфо.

Итак, нам нужно поймать создание `Popup`'а, и навесить на него свой стиль. Кроме того, нам понадобится свойство для дополнительного контента. Это тянет на целый Custom Control. Так и сделаем — заведём стандартный Custom Control (Add → New Item... → Custom Control (WPF)), назовём его `DatePickerEx`. Унаследуем его от `DatePicker`, а не от `Control`. Получим такой код:

```
public class DatePickerEx : DatePicker
{
    static DatePickerEx()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(DatePickerEx),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DatePickerEx)));
    }
```

Добавим дополнительное свойство `AdditionalPopupContent` (тип `object`, стандартное `DependencyProperty`):

```
    public object AdditionalPopupContent
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(AdditionalPopupContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AdditionalPopupContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AdditionalPopupContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AdditionalPopupContent", typeof(object),
                                    typeof(DatePickerEx));
```

Чтобы получить доступ к `Popup`'у, перекроем `OnApplyTemplate`:

```
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
```

В нём найдём `Popup` по документированному имени:

```
        var popup = GetTemplateChild("PART_Popup") as Popup;
        if (popup != null)
            ApplyCustomStyle(popup);
    }
```

И применим к нему стиль. Поскольку у нас lookless control, вынесем стиль `Popup`'а в ресурсы стиля контрола, и установим на них ссылку через `DynamicResource`:

```
    void ApplyCustomStyle(Popup popup)
    {
        var calendar = popup.Child as Calendar;
        if (calendar == null)
            return;
        calendar.SetResourceReference(Calendar.StyleProperty, "DatePickerEx_CustomPopup");
    }
}
```

С этой частью всё. Теперь, сам стиль. Когда мы создали custom control, стиль по умолчанию добавился в `Themes\Generic.xaml`. Мы не хотим полностью переписывать стиль, так что мы базируемся на стиле для `DatePicker`'а, и просто добавляем стиль с нужным именем в ресурсы.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:DatePickerEx}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DatePicker}}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Calendar" x:Key="DatePickerEx_CustomPopup">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        x:Name="PART_Root">
                                <CalendarItem x:Name="PART_CalendarItem"/>
                                <ContentControl
                                    Content="{Binding Parent.TemplatedParent.AdditionalPopupContent,
                                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Часть `<ContentControl Content="{Binding Parent.TemplatedParent.AdditionalPopupContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>` и есть вставка нашего дополнительного контента. `RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}` начинает от `Calendar`, `Parent` — это `Popup`, а `Parent.TemplatedParent` — это `DataPickerEx`.

Ну что же, теперь надо использовать наш код. Пишем:

```
<local:DatePickerEx x:Name="Picker">
    <local:DatePickerEx.AdditionalPopupContent>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Click="OnNeverClick">Никогда</Button>
            <Button Click="OnAlwaysClick">Всегда</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </local:DatePickerEx.AdditionalPopupContent>
</local:DatePickerEx>
```

В code-behind

```
void OnNeverClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Picker.SelectedDate = null;
}

void OnAlwaysClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // не знаю, как вы кодируете «всегда»
}
```

Получаем результат:

[image: Результат]